# SceneKit flashes at start of animation

Tags: macos, animation, scenekit

I have a behaviour I don't understand when using SceneKit animations.
All the below code is executed in the context of the renderer:updateAtTime: delegate call.

I build my animation like this :

```
         SCNVector4 startRotation   = node.rotation ;
         SCNVector4 targetRotation  = pose.rotation ;

         CABasicAnimation    *rotAnimation   = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"rotation"] ;
         rotAnimation.fromValue  = [NSValue valueWithSCNVector4:startRotation] ;
         rotAnimation.toValue    = [NSValue valueWithSCNVector4:targetRotation] ;
         rotAnimation.duration   = duration ;
```

Now, if I do this right after :

```
         // First change the final rotation state, and then start the animation
         node.rotation  = targetRotation ;
         [node addAnimation:rotAnimation forKey:animationName] ;
```

I have a quick flash of the character at the final position, and then the animation runs from startRotation to targetRotation and remains in targetRotation position forever - which is what I want, except for the flash.

If I do this instead (just exchange the two last lines order) :

```
         // First start the animation and then set the final position
         [node addAnimation:rotAnimation forKey:animationName] ;
         node.rotation  = targetRotation ;
```

I don't have the flash, but when the animation ends, the character goes back to initial position, which is not what I want.

I read about fillMode and removedOnCompletion, but setting removedOnCompletion to NO is not the right thing to do, as it leaves animations "running" forever.

How to avoid the initial flash ?

Comment: I think you should do your animation outside of `renderer:updateAtTime:` as the docs say that any scene changes are applied immediately. (So I'm guessing the node is getting updated before the animation has been added.)

Comment: Well, nearly... I think you are right when you say "do your animation outside of renderer:updateAtTime:". However, not because changes are applied immediately. I have been through lengthy investigations, and I think I now understand what is happening. To make it short, my code works perfectly (no flash) if executed inside renderer:didRenderScene:atTime:. I will write a detail explanation and answer my own question for the sake of documenting and helping others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the story. As Apple states in its documentation, SceneKit rendering happens in a loop, and several delegate methods are called in the following order :

1 - renderer:updateAtTime:

(SceneKit runs animations)

2 - renderer:didApply:AnimationsAtTime:

(...)

4 - renderer:willRenderSCne:atTime:

(**SceneKit renders the scene**)

5 - renderer:didRenderScene:atTime:

Now, the documentation for addAnimation:forKey: also says : "Newly added animations begin executing **after the current run loop cycle ends**".

I traced the value of the rotation for my nodes and their presentation nodes. When I add the animation in renderer:updateAtTime: (step 1), I first set the node target position, and then add an animation, but this animation won't be executed before the current run loop ends. So SceneKit renders this final position (between step 4 and 5), and then, at next cycle, SceneKit will run the animation (between step 1 and 2) and the presentationNode gets the right values and is rendered again between steps 4 and 5 - therefore the flash.

To the opposite, if I add the animation in renderer:didRenderScene:atTime: (step 5), the cycle ends, the animation is scheduled and runs (between step 1 and 2) before SceneKit reaches the rendering time (between step 4 and 5). No flash.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting the node's rotation twice: once with the animation, and once by direct manipulation. They're interfering with each other.

Try removing `node.rotation = targetRotation` completely.

Comment: Yes, I do this. But this is Apple recommended way of doing animations (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW1). If you don't set node.rotation, then at the end of the animation, you are back to the initial value. The problem is that it seems needed to do so before the animation is added - which is an undocumented point - but this flashes the animation.